# Current FMS with COMM tunning function capability?

Tags: radio-communications, fms

I am currently more familiar with GARMIN 1000 systems than with the ones that are used nowadays in airliners.

I know that you can tune a NAV aid from the FMC in an airliner. Actually, modern FMS come with the auto-tune capability for NAV aids (which helps to achieve the desired RNAV or PBN requirements). My question is if there is something similar regarding the COMMS frequencies. Let me elaborate:

With Garmin 1000, you can even select COMMS frequencies from the FMS. You can actually search an aerodrome and, if selected, it will automatically tune the COMM frequency for that aerodrome in the standby freq. Therefore:

- Is there any mechanism like this one in the FMS of typical modern airliners? (a320, b737, a380...). If not, could you please give me examples of typical GA aircrafts that come with FMS with that capability?
- Is there any way that we can we select comms frequencies from a typical FMS in an A320 or B737, or do we have to use always the nav/comms station to do so?

Answer (score 3):

On Airbus/Boeing airliners, the Comms system is completely separate from the Nav system, so - no.

The 787 has the ability to pre-store lots of Comms frequencies, so that you've already got the numbers in the box. But it doesn't have the modern light aircraft capability to tell you that this frequency is this airport and that facility.